# Highcharts : Change color of series when hovering other series

Tags: highcharts

I have an issue where I want to change the fill color of a column series when hovering another series. (This is to visualize related series)

I succeeded in changing the color on mouseOver, but I'm not able to restore the color on mouseOut.

The code I have until now is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6CA3/1/)

```
var hoverSerie;
var originalColor;
var newColor = '#a760d6'

$(function () {
    var t = $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series:[{
            events: {
                mouseOver: function() {

                    hoverSeries = this.chart.series[2]

                    originalColor = hoverSeries.options.color;
                    hoverSeries.options.color = newColor;
                    hoverSeries.update(hoverSeries.options);
                },
                mouseOut: function(){

                    if(originalColor)
                    {
                       hoverSeries.options.color = originalColor;
                       hoverSeries.update(); 
                    }
                }
            },
            animation : false,
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            animation : false,
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            animation : false,
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

When hovering (mouseOver) the top stacked series (light blue) the color of the bottom (black) series. For one or other reason, the mouse out event is working differently as the mousOver event. The code appears to loop when doing a mouseOut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when doing `update` inside `mouseOut` the `redraw`-part of the update causes `mouseOut` to be called recursively, eventually leading to "stack size exceeded". In **[this updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6CA3/2/)** I've used a boolean to prevent it from happening recursively, which seems to be working for me in Chrome. Hope it it what you were looking for. The only real change is the addition of the `mouseWasOver` variable used in both `mouseOver` and `mouseOut`.

This appears to be a bug(?) related to calling `update` inside `mouseOut` that was reported as early as 2011 on [their GitHub](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/182), and 2010 on [their forum](http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=8921).